# Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, analog

A c515c (8 bit A/D) has the following parameters

Fosc= 11 mega hertz , Vagnd= 0 volts, Varef= 4 volts

What is the +_1 bit round-off % for a 3 volt, measurement?

Comment: What have you done to figure this out, have you looked at datasheet specs, how are you using the A/D.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [datasheet](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/c515_ds_0203.pdf?folderId=db3a304412b407950112b408e8c90004&fileId=db3a304412b407950112b41a32ac29e3) (which should always be the first point of reference for stuff like this) it has a 10 bit ADC. This means the resolution is 2^10 = 1024.
The actual unadjusted error (precision) is +/- 2 LSB. Ignoring this the basic resolution is simply 3 / 1024 = ~3mV. Including it means it could read +/- 9mV from the actual value.
The image below is from page 74

[image: c515c ADC specs]